# using jquery to delay loading php page 30sec

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i posted delay loading with php but everybody said this is difficult

and it better using jquery.

anyone give me some hint or reference?

---

i want to make my php page delay loading with some image(loading image)

such like

http://www.businessbee.com/wp-content/uploads/24534/loading_home.gif

i have 3 php page

from first page if click submit button, next page is loading.php page which

display loading image and 30sec later i want to redirect to

third page final.php.

redirection and delay function is no problem , problem is

when start to delay loading image is not showing..

i want loading image show to user while delay 30sec

```
<?php
$delaytime=30;
for ($x=0; $x<$delaytime; $x++) {
  echo " ";
  sleep(1);
}

header("Location: /final.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();

?>
```

Comment: I believe the time is in milliseconds. Did you try `sleep(1000)`?

Comment: @g_m `sleep` is in seconds. `usleep` is in microseconds.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You are right. I stand corrected.

Comment: this is not milisecond...it second..so it 30second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loading.php` page should just be:

```
<img src="loading_image_here.gif" />
<a href="final.php">Click here if the browser does not redirect you</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = "final.php";
    },30000); // 30 seconds
</script>
```

Note that most people probably won't want to wait 30 seconds unless there's a damn good reason...